# Make EF generated query efficient

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Currently I need to copy records from Tabel1(SourceTable) to Table2(TargetTable) when record doesn't exist in Table2 along with few other condition .

I am using EntityFramework to do this job. When i used the below query to fetch records from source table i noticed Entity framework is using Left join with target table which is very slow, The same query when i replaced with not exist it worked fast.

so how to implement not exist in the below scenario?

Along with you can see 2 inner join with same table ? Why that so ?

In general how to overwrite EF generated query ?

We can do the above by mapping stored procedure but i am expecting without using SP mapping.

[image: Below is the Entity diagram]

Query i have used to fetch :

```
var records = dal.SourceTransactions.Where((o) =>
                  o.Policy.Quote.Type == "1"
             && (o.TransactionType == 1 || o.TransactionType == 2 || o.TransactionType == 3 || o.TransactionType == 4)

               && o.TransactionDate < System.DateTime.Now &&
                o.TargetTransaction == null);
```

generated EF query:

```
{SELECT 
[Filter1].[ID1] AS [ID], 
[Filter1].[TransactionDate] AS [TransactionDate], 
[Filter1].[TransactionType] AS [TransactionType], 
[Filter1].[PolicyId] AS [PolicyId]
FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID1], [Extent1].[TransactionDate] AS [TransactionDate], [Extent1].[TransactionType] AS [TransactionType], [Extent1].[PolicyId] AS [PolicyId]
    FROM    [dbo].[SourceTransactions] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Policies] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PolicyId] = [Extent2].[ID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Quotes] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[QuoteId] = [Extent3].[ID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Quotes] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[QuoteId] = [Extent4].[ID]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[TransactionType] IN (1,2,3,4)) AND
   ([Extent1].[TransactionDate] < (SysDateTime())) AND (N'1' = [Extent3].[Type])      AND     ([Extent4].[Type] IS NOT NULL) ) 
 AS [Filter1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TargetTransactions] AS [Extent5] ON [Filter1].[ID1] = [Extent5].   [SourceTransactionID]
WHERE [Extent5].[SourceTransactionID] IS NULL}
```

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? I assume you are using v4, since you don't specify. We are onto version 6 now, and I wouldn't be surprised if the its better (hint, 6 doesn't use 4 under the covers anymore).

Comment: BTW, doing bulk SQL operations using an ORM is not a good idea. create a pure SQL script that does that instead.

Comment: Aron : Entity Framework 5.0

Comment: HighCore: Yes i agree with you . but we have implemented ORM, so expecting some solution around there ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force an `EXISTS` query like so:

```
 dal.SourceTransactions
    .Where(o => o.Policy.Quote.Type == "1"
             && (o.TransactionType == 1 
                 || o.TransactionType == 2 
                 || o.TransactionType == 3 
                 || o.TransactionType == 4)
             && o.TransactionDate < System.DateTime.Now
             && !dal.TargetTransactions
                    .Any(t => t.SourceTransactionID == o.ID)
```

So you explicitly create a subquery for the `TargetTransactions`. I assume that `dal` is a context instance, so it also exposes `TargetTransactions`.

Of course it's too bad that you have to massage EF into the best query. This may be one of the areas where EF 6 is improved, maybe worth a try.

Comment: Aaaah, cool idea to use the context in the Where clause :) I didn't think it would be possible to force an EXISTS.

Comment: Yes, we can use Any but target transaction is not a collection means we can't use any there. There is a one to one mapping between source transaction and target transaction...

Comment: But you could use `dal.TargetTransactions` couldn't you? Or `dat.DbSet<dal.TargetTransaction>`?

Comment: Yes, I could use dal.TargetTransactions but i cant use Any operator in that. since it's not the collection . Guess i am clear

Comment: Not a collection? Isn't `dal` a context? If it isn't, you should try to get this to the context level.

Comment: Great its working .. i confused with **o.TargetTransaction** which i used initially .. anyhow thanks mate